# python how to append to file in zip archive

Tags: python, compression, zip

If I do something like this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 

zip = ZipFile(archive, "a")  

for x in range(5):
    zip.writestr("file1.txt", "blabla")
```

It will create an archive with 5 files all named "file1.txt". What I want to achieve is having one compressed file to which every loop iteration appends some content. Is it possible without having some kind of auxiliary buffer and how to do this?

Comment: @MoSander: I think that mnowotka wants to append content to a single file within the archive, not append a file to the archive.

Comment: @abw333 yes, I see that too now. Appending a file to the archive was what *I* wanted to do when I came to this post ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impossible with zipfile package but writing to compressed files is supported in [gzip](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html):

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
f = gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

Comment: But gzip can only contain one file.

Comment: Yep, but it can be used together with [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) or [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: When you use it with tar, you can not write directly to a single file like this anymore :)

Comment: What I mean is that the data can be written in gzip-compressed files that are then packed into a tar archive later in the same script.

Comment: There is no way one can "append" to a file in zip file using the python zipfile library. Please suggest if there is some other library which I can use to append content to a file.

Answer (score 11):

Its quite possible to append files to compressed archive using Python.

Tested on linux mint 14,Python 2.7

```
import zipfile

#Create compressed zip archive and add files
z = zipfile.ZipFile("myzip.zip", "w",zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
z.write("file1.ext")
z.write("file2.ext")
z.printdir()
z.close()

#Append files to compressed archive
z = zipfile.ZipFile("myzip.zip", "a",zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
z.write("file3.ext")
z.printdir()
z.close()

#Extract all files in archive
z = zipfile.ZipFile("myzip.zip", "r",zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
z.extractall("mydir")
z.close()
```

Comment: I believe the clear reading of the question is that the OP wants to append to `file1.ext`, adding additional content to that existing file in multiple iterations, as opposed to adding additional files.

Comment: the question is about to append data into the same file entity inside the ZIP archive but appending another file entity into the same ZIP archive