# how to create a file in a folder of a zip in python?

Tags: python, file

I want to create file in a folder in a zip file using the zipfile library. Something like

```
with ZipFile(filepath, 'w') as myzip:   
    myzip.write("text.txt")
```

works for normal files, but not for folders.

> the sturcture should be like this: zipfile.zip/folder/text.txt

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680562/python-how-to-append-to-file-in-zip-archive , esp. the second response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to write files in new directories for a zip using `zipfile` package, here is an example writing same file to different new folders

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("./m.zip", 'w') as z: 
  z.write("./m.cpp", "./folder54/m.cpp")
  z.write("./m.cpp", "./folder55/m.cpp")
```